# on update input not getting full string from database laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

in my blade i have

```
value={{$categorie->category_name}}
```

this value on database="IR الترتيب في المجموعة"
but  I just get "IR" in input value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one

```php
value="{{$categorie->category_name}}"
```